# Setting a slice as noindex in Datastore does not take any effect

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

Given,

```
type Person struct {
 Name string `datastore:"name"`
 Pets []Pet `datastore:"pets,noindex"`
}

type Pet struct {
 Age int `datastore:"age"`
}
```

Datastore still indexes `Pets` field and all fields in `Pet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `noindex` will only affect new entities. Entities that have been previously saved will remain indexed until you over-write them.